# Use a .p12 File from classpath for GoogleCredential

Tags: java, private-key, google-oauth

I am making a java command line application packaged in a single JAR file that uses some of Google's API.

I need to set up a GoogleCredential object from a private key "Credentials.p12".

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId("xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP, DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER, DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_ORGUNIT))
                    .setServiceAccountUser(emailAccount)
                    //THE CODE BELOW IS IMPORTANT: I need to change this
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("Credentials.p12"))
                    .build();

        directory = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("My Cmd App")
                .build();
```

Right now I was able to make it work, but the file "Credentials.p12" is located outside the packaged JAR file.

How do I make it work using a p12 file from inside the JAR?

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.19.1/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.Builder#setServiceAccountPrivateKey(java.security.PrivateKey)), the only other alternative that I think I can use is the method variant that uses a PrivateKey object. I am thinking of using InputStream to get the p12 file from the classpath:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Credentials.p12");
```

I absolutely have no idea how to do that.

Before you answer, please make sure that you have experience using the Google OAuth2 library. And Please, no hacks like copying the resource to a temporary file: the singular version of Credential.p12 should remain inside the JAR for a reason.

Comment: What you think sounds good, you'll just have to replace the FileInputStream here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.10.0-beta/com/google/api/client/auth/security/PrivateKeys.java#82

Comment: another issue that I have: I absolutely have no idea what the alias and password is for the p12 file that google provides... ill try to check the docs later on.

Comment: update: answered my own question, did some digging on the structure of the p12 file and used @zapl suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging through the `GoogleCredential.Builder` class source code I realized the following:

- the password for the p12 file generated from Google's developer
  console is always `"notasecret"` as well as the password for  the alias
- the alias for the private key is always `"privatekey"`

using the following code to build the private key from the resource InputStream:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Credentials.p12"), "notasecret".toCharArray());
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("privatekey", "notasecret".toCharArray());
```

I was able to load the private key into the GoogleCredential Builder:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId("xxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP, DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER, DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_ORGUNIT))
                    .setServiceAccountUser(emailAccount)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(pk) //<----THIS
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just specify the key file when instantiating the the credential.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all())
            .build();
```