# Load file onto hadoop datanode from JAR

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle, jar, google-analytics-api

I am running a Hadoop job on multiple datanodes. For that I supply a `.jar` file containing my job.

Within the job I want to access the Google Analytics API (See for a [introduction tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java#3_setup_the_sample)). For authentication the Analytics API requires a `.p12` file for authentication. Basically I have [this problem](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/857). Using *gradle* I am able to pack this file into my `jar` file:

```
from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

and the file is in the root of the `jar`. Now I try to modify the example code to read the `.p12` file from inside the jar *or* access it any other way.

I've tried multiple ways but always end up with a `NullPointerException`. Here is my most recent try:

```
File file = new File(HelloAnalytics.class.getResource("client_secrets.p12").toURI());

HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport
        .newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsReportingScopes.all())
        .build();
```

I've also tried reading the file with a `BufferedReader` and export it back onto the filesystem:

```
    File file = null;
    String resource = "client_secrets.p12";
    URL res = getClass().getResource(resource);
    if (res.toString().startsWith("jar:")) {
        InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
        file = File.createTempFile("client_secrets", ".p12");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        file.deleteOnExit();
    } else {
        //this will probably work in your IDE, but not from a JAR
        file = new File(res.getFile());
    }

    if (file != null && !file.exists()) {
        throw new IOException("...");
    }

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport
            .newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsReportingScopes.all())
            .build();
```

Any ideas on how to access the `jar` properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365546/use-a-p12-file-from-classpath-for-googlecredential should answer your question

Comment: it did! that you. Add it as an answer and Ill mark it as correct