# Using private key (p12) embedded in a jar file for GoogleCredential Builder

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheets API to query a spreadsheet on Google. The code just works fine when run from inside eclipse. But, when the project is packed to a jar (say, spreadsheets-api.jar) and used from a different project as maven dependency, I am running into issues with the following method call:

```
public static Sheets createService() throws GoogleServiceInitException {
        if (properties == null)
            init();
        URL keyfile = GoogleSpreadSheetService.class.getResource(getValue(PropertyEnum.PRIVATEKEY_FILE));
        if (keyfile == null)
            throw new GoogleServiceInitException("Missing private key file");
        Credential credential;
        try {
            credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId(getValue(PropertyEnum.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID))
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(Paths.get(keyfile.toURI()).toFile())
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES).build();
            return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();

        } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            logger.error(APGeneralUtilities.stacktraceToString(e));
            throw new GoogleServiceInitException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The issue is with method `setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File` which only takes a `java.io.File` as parameter. So, when I try to access this file by referring to the embedded P12 file in the jar as an URL and then coverting it to File using this line of code - `Paths.get(keyfile.toURI()).toFile()`, the code bombs with a `java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException`.

The problem is pretty clear. I need to refer to the P12 file as a stream, and I could do that by using Class.getResourceAsStream() or other alternatives, but Google's credential builder will only take a file as parameter.

What are my options now? The way I see it, to work with sheets api, I just have to get the stream, copy it to temp file, then give that file's path as a parameter to the Credentials builder, and finally delete the temp file after everything is done. Is there a simpler way to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a .p12 File from classpath for GoogleCredential](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365546/use-a-p12-file-from-classpath-for-googlecredential)

Comment: Please close my question, found that this is a duplicate..